# AngularJS: Inject service or directives dynamically in controller (without including them in angular.module's square brackets beforehand, see example)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

My AngularJS app has pages with dynamic tabs. One example is an *Account settings* page that has a bunch of tabs like `Profile`, `Billing`, `Password`, etc. These tabs are added **dynamically** based on what modules the user has enabled. I use `ngRoute` to load the tab content in ng-view.

Please see this example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/NIvMRw65VHMxZjTluKxQ?p=preview

The code doesn't work because I haven't included `moduleOne` and `moduleTwo` in the list of modules only `['ngRoute']`

Here is a working version:

http://run.plnkr.co/8xIuvMIZSBYuITyN/working.html

In `working.html` I have included all the modules:

```
     angular.module('ngApp', ['ngRoute', 'moduleOne', 'moduleTwo']);
```

and so it works!

*So my question to you is this:*

**How do I include `moduleOne` in `one.html` and `moduleTwo` in `two.html` respectively?**

Because I don't want to include all the modules like this

`['ngRoute', 'moduleOne', 'moduleTwo', ...unknown modules]`

I just want to include

`['ngRoute']`

in my index.html, and load the rest of the modules inside the templates so they are loaded as and when needed.

**How can I do this?**

P.S. If you can correct my `plnkr` or post some code, that will be most helpful!

Comment: `ngRoute` must the their at config phase, otherwise how can you make your routing working.why you want to load modules template wise?

Comment: Hi, you can certainly add routes dynamically. You can save a reference to $routeProvider in `config` phase and then use that to add routes in controller. You can also use $route.routes hash to add them. I'm using a mobile phone so unable to post an example but I'm doing that in my main app without any issues..

Answer (score 0):

Without using a build tool to allow for imports, one option would be to put things in a namespace on the window.  When the script files are included, they will add themselves to the modules array.  The array is then used as dependencies for the main app.

```
//in each of the deps:
window.modules = window.modules || [];
window.modules.push('moduleOne');

// another dep:
window.modules = window.modules || [];
window.modules.push('moduleTwo');

//in the main script loading the app
window.modules = window.modules || [];
window.modules.push('ngRoute');
var app = angular.module('ngApp', window.modules);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/zyae1Y08Pe3WY3zbcutH?p=preview

The down side of doing this is that it dirties up `window`.  You risk some other script also depending on `window.modules` messing with your stuff.  You can better namespace it, but using something like webpack, browserify, systemjs, or others... would allow you to avoid that whole thing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.. So do you think it is possible to do so with systemjs, etc? Can you give me an example on how to so it..

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching I was able to make it work. The trick was using the **ocLazyLoad** library.

**Here is the working plunk:**

http://goo.gl/wPeCAF

Let me know what you guys think?